# How do I replace "Log Out" from the Menu with "My Orders"?

Tags: logout

After the user clicks on **Log In**, the **Log In** option changes to **Log Out** in the menu. How can I make it change to **My Orders** instead, redirecting to /my-account/orders/?

So basically now it's changing from:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a class="porto-link-login" href="https://website.com/my-account/"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Log In</a></li>
```

to:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="https://website.com/my-account/customer-logout/"><i class="avatar"></i>Log out</a></li>
```

But I'd want it to change to:

```
<li class="menu-item"><a href="https://website.com/my-account/orders/"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>My Orders</a></li>
```

Comment: not clear for me  ?

Comment: Are you using any plugins?

Comment: Vikrant, I made it a bit more clear maybe. 

Lots of plugins yep.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `is_user_logged_in()` function to create a `if / else` statement in your menu.

Here a quick code.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    ?>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="https://website.com/my-account/orders/"><i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>My Orders</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="https://website.com/my-account/customer-logout/"><i class="avatar"></i>Log out</a></li>
    <?php 

} 
else {

    ?>
    <li class="menu-item"><a class="porto-link-login" href="https://website.com/my-account/"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Log In</a></li>
    <?php 
}
?>
```

You could also work with the current user capabilities `current_user_can` to create a better filter for your menus.

I will give you the documentation below if you want to go further.

Documentation : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

Comment: Your solution worked, in combination with 
https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-in-menus/ 
and 
http://xyzscripts.com/wordpress-plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/

Any idea what I would have had to add to functions.php in order to just add that as the last item in the menu?